# Search based on PHP array field

Tags: javascript, php, html

i am trying to do google search from my page and the search is based on specific set of strings.so the following code has a PHP array field with some values ..so if i need to use them when performing search ,how to do that,i tried to work on following code but it is not working .

```
enter code here


    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
     <?php $fieldArray=array('fruits','gold','pen');?>
     <script>
     function searchLink()
      {
    var link1 = document.getElementById("search").value;            
     window.location.href = 'https://www.google.co.in/?q='+link1;
     }
     $(function() {
     var availableTags = <?php echo json_encode($fieldArray)?>
     $( "#search" ).autocomplete({
     source: availableTags
     });
      });
     </script>
     </head>
     <input type="text" name="search" id="search" style="width:400px;"/>
     <input type="button" name="searchBtn" id="searchBtn" value="Search"  onclick="searchLink()"/>
```

Comment: You're talking about the meta keywords ?

Comment: i don't think so..all i want is perform a simple search in google based on keyword entered on search along with values stored in php array field ,how can i do that

Answer (score 0):

I think you want "`fruits,gold,pen`" as autocomplete in search box.

In js You missed **semicolon(;)** after var declaration.

```
var availableTags = <?php echo json_encode($fieldArray)?>;
```

Answer (score 0):

missing **;**

```
var availableTags = <?php echo json_encode($fieldArray)?>;
```